# ASP .net mvc 5 Identity framework packages

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, asp.net-identity

I have installed the current stable version (2.0.0) of asp .net identity (core, entityframework and OWIN), however visual studio is giving errors based off of previous alpha version.

For example:
I'm calling the `FindByName<TUser>()` method on my UserManager object, but I'm getting an error saying the method call is missing arguments and should be `FindByName<TUser, **TKey**>()` instead.

I searched 'TKey', and found this to be a part of previous alpha release but on in the stable 2.0.0

How could I resolve these errors?

Comment: Did you delete all old DLL's from the bin directory?

Comment: Deleting DLL's unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting errors in your code or the framework code? Can you show the relevant code?